# How to solve for x in: $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This is very simple algebra for using the shell method, but unfortunately my algebra is extremely weak.

I need to express the function in terms of x but am having trouble.

> $$y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$$

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square both sides and take the reciprocal:

$$y=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\implies y^2=\frac1{x^2+1}\implies x^2+1=\frac1{y^2}\implies x^2=\frac1{y^2}-1=\frac{1-y^2}{y^2}\implies$$

$$\implies x=\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}y\;\;,\;\;\text{defined for all}\;\;y\neq 0\;.$$

Note that you can also put $\;\sqrt{y^2}=|y|\;$ above and use the double sign $\;\pm\;$ in front of the whole left expression.

Comment: $y$ is positive, therefore $|y|=y$ and you have to use the $\pm$

Comment: Ah, indeed so @gammatester. I forgot completely where did that $\;y\;$ come from. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you; is there a specific rule or reasoning that allows you to take the reciprocal of both sides of the equation, so that they will still be equal?

Comment: The reasoning is algebra, @SpagGuy...sparing, of course, the case(s) where the term going to the denominator vanishes. That's why we must remark $\;y\neq 0\;$ . In general, and with this condition, we have that $$\frac1a=b\iff a=\frac1b$$, or in words: first multiply the equality by $\;a\;$ , and then divide the resulting equality by $\;b\;$

Comment: The multiply by a / divide by b thing makes perfect sense, thank you.  This is what a 6-year break in math does to you!

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\Rightarrow y^2=\frac 1{x^2+1}\Rightarrow x^2+1=\frac 1{y^2}\Rightarrow x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{y}$$

Assuming $y\ne0$

Comment: You can define y as $0 \le y \le 1$

Comment: I thought that as well, although It's not really said that the expression must be solved in $\mathbb{R}$ and hence I decided to go for the minimum assumptions choice :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Multiply the left side by $\sqrt{x^2+1}$
2. Divide the $1$ by y
3. Square both sides
4. Isolate $x^2$
5. Take the square root of both sides:

$$y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\\
\left(\sqrt{x^2 + 1}\right)^2 = \left(\dfrac{1}{y}\right)^2\\x^2+1-1=\dfrac{1}{y^2}-1\\x^2=\dfrac{1-y^2}{y^2}\\x=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-y^2}{y^2}}\\x=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{y}\\y\neq0$$